# How to position a liquid/elastic textbox next to a button?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, stylesheet

I want to position a textbox and a button next to each other in an 'elastic' or 'liquid' way (what's the correct term?) like so:

[image: layout]
<sub>(source: [ocactus.org](http://www.ocactus.org/liquid.gif))</sub>

When placed in a container of arbitrary width (incl. browser window resizing), the button should right align and take up as much width as it requires while the textbox should use the remaining width. Unfortunately the button's width cannot be fixed in CSS as it depends on the caption (different actions, languages etc.).

What is a good solution for the above that works cross browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get this to work within a table (I know, but it works) where it would correctly handle page resizing as well as the value of the button changing:

```
<table class="elastic">
    <tr>
        <td><input class="textbox" type="text"></td>
        <td class="button"><input type="button" value="Test Button"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There may be a <div> alternative out there for styling.

**EDIT:** I revamped my example to use the following style sheet:

```
.elastic { width:100%; }
.elastic .textbox { width: 100%; }
.elastic .button { width: 1%; }
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid tables but I guess that's the best/only way to achieve what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a definitive answer without seeing some code but the following will size the input 50% of the browser width with the button next to it.

```
input {width:50%}

<input>
<button>save</button>
```

Comment: ..but I want the textbox to be 'the rest of the available width', not a fixed percentage of the brwoser width?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="widebox">
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var w = $(".widebox");
  $(".widebox input:text").css({ width: (w.width - (w.children("button:first").width + 20)) });
});
</script>
```

Note: Be sure to include the jQuery library in your document's <head>. For speed I recommend using the one hosted by Google: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery extension I wrote based on NGJ Graphics' answer. It takes into account multiple buttons such as Ok/Cancel options.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    widebox: function() {
      var el = $(this);
      var width = 0;
      el.children("button").each(function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
      });
      el.children("input:text").css({ width: (el.width() - (width + 40)) });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```